# Rails, How to mark an order as completed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I need a way to apply a method I made to an order I select. Or find another way to mark something as complete.

This is what i tried so far. But i don't mind trying something completely new.
So I have these orders that I display in the view like so:

```
.col-md-12
  .admindash
    %h1 Admin Dashboard
    .text-norm
      Welcome to the admin dashboard here you can see incoming and outgoing orders.

.row
  .col-md-8
    - for order in @order
      %h2
        = order.user.name
      .orderpanel
        .clientarea
          Client name:
          = order.user.name
          %br
          Client email:
          = order.user.email
          %br
          Client address ... -->:
          %br
          = order.user.address_line_1
          %br
          = order.user.address_line_2
          %br
          = order.user.postcode
          %br
          = order.user.city
          %br
          = order.user.country
        .delivarea
          %br
          delivery_name:
          = order.delivery_name
          %br
          company_name:
          = order.company_name
          %br
          delivery_address1:
          = order.delivery_address1
          %br
          delivery_address2:
          = order.delivery_address2
          %br
          delivery_address3:
          = order.delivery_address3
          %br
          delivery_city:
          = order.delivery_city
          %br
          delivery_postcode:
          = order.delivery_postcode
          %br
          phone:
          = order.phone
          %br
          package_contents:
          = order.package_contents
          %br
          description_content:
          = order.description_content
          %br
          contents_value:
          = order.contents_value
          %br
          cf_reference:
          = order.id
          CR
          %br
          reference_number:
          = order.reference_number
        .tac
          restricted_items:
          = order.restricted_items
          %br
          terms_conditions:
          = order.terms_conditions
          %br
          insurance:
          = order.insurance
          = order.id
  .col-md-4.sidebar
    = paginate @order
    = link_to "Data Control", rails_admin_path, :class => 'btn-danger btn'
    %p
    = link_to "Back to Dashboard", :back, :class => 'btn-danger btn'
```

I want to add a button to the page so that I can mark orders complete maybe make a table with all orders and a button that says mark as complete.

So I ran a migration to add the boolean class of `complete`.

```
class AddCompleteToOrder < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :orders, :complete, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

Then in orders controller I made:

```
def complete
  order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
  order.complete!
  # handle response
end
```

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def complete!
    update(complete: true)
  end

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  get 'home/index'
  root 'home#index'
  #pages
  get '/why' => 'pages#why'
  get '/trak' => 'pages#trak'
  get '/contact' => 'pages#contact'
  get '/mydms' => 'pages#mydms'
  get '/air' => 'pages#air'
  get '/ocean' => 'pages#ocean'
  get '/road' => 'pages#road'
  get '/courier' => 'pages#courier'
  get 'fulfilment' => 'pages#fulfilment'
  get 'express' => 'pages#express'

  resources :dashboard
  get 'dadmin' => 'dashboard#dadmin'
  get 'myorders' => 'dashboard#myorders'
  get 'label' => 'dashboard#label'
  resources "contacts", only: [:new, :create]

  devise_for :users
  as :user do
    get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'
    put 'users' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'
  end

  resources "orders"
  get "confirm" => "confirmations#show"
  get 'dconfirmation' => 'orders#confirmation'
end
```

So I now need some way to update a specific order. Like list all orders @order.id then select that order to user that method. I don't know what I'm doing as I'm new to Rails. Please help. I just need to indicate that an order is now completed.

I don't mind how I mark a order as complete, it just needs to remember this if the page is reloaded and my site does use jQuery. Is there a method I can do that through?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options, but here's one that keeps your controller restful.

First - Instead of a boolean, I use a datetime.

```
class AddCompleteToOrder < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :orders, :completed_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

In the controller, just use the update method, but have it respond_to js

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to [:admin, @order] }
  format.js { render :update }
end
```

Make an update.js.erb (or haml) view.  Looks like you're using haml.

```
- order_list_item = render :partial => 'admin/orders/order', :locals => { :order => @order }
$("##{dom_id(order)}").replaceWith('#{j(order_list_item)}')
```

You can reuse your order partial.

In the order partial, add a button or link.  I think you could also use button_to instead.

```
= link_to "Completed", admin_order_path(order, 'order[completed]' => true), :remote => true, :method => :put
```

And remember to add the dom_id to your _order.html.haml partial.  Haml gives you a convenient way to do that.

Move this into it's own partial, so instead of

```
- for order in @order
```

You would have

```
# /admin/orders/_order.html.haml

%div[order]
  ... All the other order code from the earlier for loop
```

and call it like so

```
= render @orders  # Change your instance variable name to "@orders" to match rails conventions
```

In the model, handle completed and completed=

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  def completed
    !completed_at.nil?
  end

  def completed=(state=false)
    completed_at = Time.now if state
  end

end
```

Check the developer tools (in chrome or safari) response output if you don't see the page update at first.  You can see errors this way in the response body.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time i been working on this for hours this looks promising. Ill look at it later. I need to take a break but i really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi there so i tryed this and i was wondering if you could help im having a problem. It seems to be throwing a jquery error. Here are the two screen grabs from that. It seems as if the js.haml is not working. I changed it a little by adding :javascript. Here are the screenshots. It does not work either way.

also the = link_to "Completed", admin_order_path(order, 'order[completed]' => true), :remote => true, :method => :put Changed to :

 
= link_to "Completed", admin_order_path(@order, 'order[completed]' => true), :remote => true, :method => :put Because else it threw a undefined local error.

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/9274f125f9eeda0005b4686c0d76ddec.png
http://i.gyazo.com/155f6fd472eb8628e26c646de492b1c8.png

Comment: If i close and reopen the dev tools. I get a action controller link. for no template for orders/show. I wonder if that helps. Any ideas it stumped me please feel free to ask anything for clarification im still learning.

Comment: The screenshots indicate the url you are hitting is not valid.  Take a look at the url by looking at the source in the index view.  Also - include your routes in your original question - the url your are hoping to create is the same as the 'show' order url - the method is changed to :put and that will hit the update action (instead of show).

Comment: There is no index view set up for this page i will include my controller that will explain it. The issue does not even recognise the update.js.haml it does not matter what is in that file it does not pick it up.

Comment: Basically i have it to a point in which if i click complete it just says im missing the template of orders/show. Have i done something very wrong. I changed the order, to @order because it was a undefined method order. That is the only thing differant i have done from your instructions.

Comment: I cant add the routes file as a edit because a peer is not letting me. So instead ill give you a screenshot sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In orders_controller.rb

```
  def completed_orders
    # Get order from DB
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])

    if !@order.completed?
      if @order.completed!
        flash[:notice] = "Your order has been marked complete. Email notification will be sent!" 
        # Can also do more stuff here.
      else
        flash[:alert] = "Something is hmmm not right..."
        # Can also do more stuff here.
      end
    end
    redirect_to request.referrer
  end
```

In Order model order.rb you can enumerate, add status column as an integer to the orders table. Below you enumerate from 0 to 1 This way you can simply know 0 in the status column is "processing", 1 will be "completed". You can also add more in your enumeration in your orders.rb You can also ininstead use boolean values like 0 as false and 1 as true, but this has limitation to only two. SO you're better off having status column as an integer and enumerate, and you can add more like "processing, under_investigation, other_issues, completed". Here below it's just two statuses.

```
belongs_to :user, required: false
enum status: [:processing, :completed]
```

Ensure you have your routes updated after you make the completed_orders action. Maybe you have to remigrate, or update your DB etc.